# Bash Delete folder from Artifactory with Curl

Tags: bash, curl, artifactory

I am attempting to delete all folders from our Artifactory that are older than 2 weeks.

I find the files that are all older than 2 weeks with this command:

```
curl -s -u usernamd:password "URL/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=${Two_Years_Ago}&${Two_Weeks_Ago}&repos=generic-sgca" | jq -r '.results[].uri'|sed 's=/api/storage=='
```

Which will return the following:

```
https://URL/generic-sgca/KsfSettingsEngine/0.2.0-123456/latest/export/conanfile.py
```

I can delete the "conanfile.py" by running this command:

```
curl -u username:password -X DELETE https://URL/generic-sgca/KsfSettingsEngine/0.2.0-123456/latest/export/conanfile.py
```

However, I want to delete the entire 0.2.0-123456 folder, not just the conanfile.py file.

When I try this command:

```
curl -u username:password -X DELETE https://URL/generic-sgca/KsfSettingsEngine/0.2.0-123456
```

it returns a "Could not locate artifact" error. How can I accomplish deleting the entire artifactory folder from a curl command?

Comment: Can you try and add a slash ('/') at the end and try again?

Comment: were you able to solve this? I know is an old question, but I want to do the same. Nos just removing artifact, but also removing entire folder older than 2 or 3 weeks